# Method for casting generic objects c#

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I have a couple of objects that have a corresponding object with identical properties.

```
class Source1
{
    int id;
    string name;
    DateTime date;
}

class Destination1
{
    int id;
    string name;
    DateTime date;
}

class Source2
{
    int id;
    string code;
    double price;
}

class Destination2
{
    int id;
    string code;
    double price;
}
```

Now I want to make a method with generic types that can cast an object into his corresponding object.

```
public TDestination Cast<TSource, TDestination>(TSource source)
{
    //TDestination destination = (TDestination) source;
    return destination;
}
```

Comment: Even though the properties are identical you cannot cast an object to some unrelated (in terms of inheritance) class.

Comment: Why not use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Boris Calens pointed out Automapper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35622180/539997), which is great, but if you want to avoid using outside code, a home-made solution for your example problem is pretty simple:

```
using System.Reflection;

...

TDestination Copy<TSource, TDestination>(TSource source)
where TDestination : new()
{
    TDestination dest = new TDestination();

    foreach (FieldInfo srcField in typeof(TSource).GetFields())
    {
        foreach (FieldInfo destField in typeof(TDestination).GetFields())
        {
            if (destField.Name == srcField.Name && destField.FieldType == srcField.FieldType)
            {
                destField.SetValue(dest, srcField.GetValue(source));
            }
        }
    }

    return dest;
}
```

You could also easily loop through the properties of the respective types; specify binding flags to filter which fields/properties get copied; and expand the comparison for determining whether the two members are of the same type (i.e. checking whether one type is derived from another).

[My answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4511722/differences-between-two-objects-in-c-sharp/4523087#4523087) (which you may also find helpful) shows a similar example, comparing properties *and* fields.

Answer (score 5):

Your best option here is to introduce a common interface (or base class). There is no other way to cast an item into another.

```
public interface IItem
{
    int id {get;set;}
    string name {get;set;}
    DateTime date {get;set;}
}

class Source1 : IItem
{
    public int id {get;set;}
    public  string name {get;set;}
    public  DateTime date {get;set;}
}

class Destination1 : IItem
{
    public int id {get;set;}
    public string name {get;set;}
    public DateTime date {get;set;}
}
```

You can then just cast the object into the interface and access the properties.

```
var item1 = (IItem)sourceItem;
var item2 = (IItem)destinationItem;
```

If you don't want to do that another option would be to using reflection go trough the properties in the source and create a new object of the destination type and try to map properties with shared names. This would however create a new object and is not the same at all as casting. There are libraries such as [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) that can help you with this.

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Source1, Destination1>();
var destItem = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Destination1 >(sourceItem);
```

Comment: No DV from me, but saying "There is no other way to cast an item into another" is very [debatable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.tryconvert(v=vs.110).aspx). You might consider rewording it, or elaborating on what you mean by "cast".

Answer (score 1):

As [Magnus points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35621977/11333), if you want to actually cast, interfaces are your way to go. However, I'm thinking you might be actually looking at converting rather then casting.

I would consider checking [Automapper](http://automapper.org/) as it exists for exactly that.
From the [documentation](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Open-Generics):

```
var source = new Source<int> { Value = 10 };  
var dest = mapper.Map<Source<int>, Destination<int>>(source);  
dest.Value.ShouldEqual(10);
```

You can configure mappings between two types by either naming conventions (even custom naming conventions), custom mappers or a combination of both. The most common use case I have seen for this is mapping a datatransfer object to a model and back again.

If one object is basically the other object with some extra logic and properties the [Decorator pattern](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/head-first-design/0596007124/ch03.html) might be what you are looking for. Here you basically wrap (decorate) one object with some extra stuff and the decorating object links everything through to the original object.